# ReactJS TypeScript MUI TextField set value using useSate and add onchange event function for text filed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to ReactJS with MUI development, have below ReactJS TypeScript with MuiText filed form. Looking some help to use `useSate` method to change the textfiled value.

Also add the `onchnage` function for the text filed.  I can add the onchange function for normal text filed, unsure how to add it for MUI Text filed?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from "react"
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

import { useForm, SubmitHandler, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';


interface IFormInputs {
    filepath: string;
}

const schema = yup.object().shape({
    filepath: yup.string().min(4).required(),

});

const theme = createTheme();

export default function MuiTextField() {
    const {
        control,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm<IFormInputs>({
        resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    });
    const [filepath, setFilepath] = useState("vodeo.mp3");

    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInputs> = (data) => {
        console.log('data submitted: ', data);
        console.log('filepath: ', data.filepath);
    };

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="lg">
                <CssBaseline />
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        marginTop: 8,
                        display: 'flex',
                        flexDirection: 'column',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                >

                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                        <Box sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
                            <Grid container spacing={2}>

                                <Grid item xs={16} sm={6}>
                                    <Controller
                                        name="filepath"
                                        control={control}
                                        defaultValue=""
                                        render={({ field }) => (
                                            <TextField
                                                {...field}
                                                label="File Path"
                                                error={!!errors.filepath}
                                                helperText={errors.filepath ? errors.filepath?.message : ''}
                                                autoComplete="file-path"
                                                fullWidth
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Button
                                    type="submit"
                                    variant="contained"
                                    sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
                                >
                                    Submit
                                </Button>

                            </Grid>
                        </Box>
                    </form>
                </Box>
            </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Update:
Here is the codeshare: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-water-m47uxn?file=/src/App.tsx

When we change the text box value to `auto`, want to change the textbox value to `audio.mp3`. but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MUI Textfield have onChange too:

```
<TextField
     error={Boolean(touched.name && errors.name)}
     fullWidth
     label={t('Name')}
     name="name"
     onBlur={handleBlur}
     onChange={handleChange}
     value={values.name}
     variant="outlined"
     autoComplete="off"
/>
```

'field' in render function contains onChange.
And state of form saved in useForm. In useForm props you have to add defaultValues. And you did not pass prop type="file", maybe its your problem.

Guide about create file input with react hook form: https://refine.dev/blog/how-to-multipart-file-upload-with-react-hook-form/

Textfield api: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/

Comment: example from this page helped. https://travis.media/react-hook-form-controller-examples/.  one issue I have is change the filed value part of `onchange` event.

Comment: you can change onChange function: ... onChange={e => { ...some code with event..., setValue('filePath', newValue) }} setValue comes from useForm hook.

Comment: Didn't work this way.  I am sample here. If I change text filed to `auto`, want to change textfile value as `audio.mp3` using usestate. https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-water-m47uxn?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @sfgroups if you use react hook form, no needs to use useState. Lib is much more powerful thing. Is it works as you wish https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-tree-dw14i0

Comment: It works now, I am not aware of `setValue`. Thanks for the help.